# Z-Index Issue with WordPress Dropdown Navigation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm working on http://ashwebdev.com/ocutherm/how-it-helps/dry-eye-blepharitis/. If you hover over how it  helps in the navigation, the Dropdown works properly, but the second item is cut off and doesn't display properly. I tried playing around with Z-Index with no luck.

Comment: If you inspect the first menu item  you can see that 
<ul class="sub-menu" style="visibility: hidden;">
<li id="menu-item-305" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-305"><a href="http://#">Test</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-306" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-306"><a href="http://#">Test 2</a></li>
</ul>
and on the other menu items there is no ul element underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a  `z-index` on the parent class (`.menu-main-menu-container`)

```
.menu-main-menu-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

*I suppose you could add it to the header too, but this would keep it a little more organized.

Comment: It looks like it's the float of the `#content` pulling it out of flow, causing prior elements to fall behind it - but the float on `.menu-main-menu-container` is preventing it from flowing up - but this container's parent, the `<header>` isn't floating so it's technically still "under" the `#content`

Comment: This fixed the issue. But for some reason every time you load the page, the dropdown menu is displayed automatically until you hover over it once

Comment: Huh, strange! Let's see .. visibility is tricky. This looks like it could be a separate issue? You could add `display: none;` to `.sub-menu` and then add `.menu-item a:hover ~ .sub-menu {
display: block;
}`

Comment: That seems to have fixed the visbility, but I can't click on any of the menu items